# correct syntax for template

Tags: c++, templates, syntax

```
template <typename _Type, typename _Comparator=less<typename _Type::value_type> >
class Myclass
// and then comes the rest of my class
```

I want to create a specialized template with strings (but also working with other comparator than the default one)
I tried this but it is not compiling.

```
template <typename _Comparator=less<typename _Type::value_type> >
class Myclass<string>
```

I know that the next example works but it uses the default comparator I fixed.

```
template <>
class Myclass<string>
```

Comment: Names that begin with a `_` followed by a capital letter are reserved for the "implementation" (compiler + standard library implementation). Do not use (declare) them yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not allowed to specify default template arguments in the class template specialization. Use the following syntax to achieve what you want:

```
template <typename Comparator>
class Myclass<string, Comparator>
{
    // ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make another default template parameter:

```c++
template<class Comparator = other_functor>
class Myclass<string, Comparator> {

};
```

Comment: and then I replace other_functor by the char comparator<?

Comment: You can't specify a default template argument in the specialization.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `=less<typename _Type::value_type>` when you declare the specialization.